# Adding elements to a table from an input area

Tags: php, javascript

I am trying to have something like the image below in my PHP page.
(The links are in the comments. I was unable to post them here properly)

Once I enter the keyword and hit the "plus" it should appear in the table, along with the color to the right. The sequence of colors will be predetermined. If I enter a keyword again and hit the "plus" again, the keyword should appear just below the earlier keyword int the table. For the time being I am assuming the table consists of 5 rows and there are less than or equal to 5 keywords.

Also I want to have a submit button at the bottom that when clicked should send all the keywords now present to a PHP file. I have a form with the action attribute set to a PHP file. The table and the keyword input field are to be a part of a form.

I prefer using javascript and not PHP for many complications. Is there a way I can store all the keywords and then send it to the PHP file once the form is submitted?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: can you post the image ?

Comment: I was unable to post the image in the original post.Here they are, 3 of them:

http://postimg.org/image/o0ejt9p1f/
http://postimg.org/image/qs7xdnxif/
http://postimg.org/image/4lsbave93/

Comment: see if this helps: http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#remote-jsonp if you don't have any code for this application then that link would be a good starting point. If you do have some code and are running into any issues, then you might want to post the code here or on code review site.

Comment: I want to add the keywords to table. Also the user can enter any possible keyword. It does not have to be from a list of possible values.

Comment: then I think it would be even simpler since you won't need to check for possible values against a database.

Comment: How do I send the data to a PHP page on the submission of the form

Comment: you can do that via AJAX request as soon as the user types a value.

Comment: see if this helps: http://textextjs.com/manual/examples/tags-adding.html you can also look at some of the other examples on that site.

Comment: Could you provide me with links where I might find how to do this with AJAX?

Comment: the code is there for each example: http://textextjs.com/manual/examples.html you just need to go through them and see what works for you. You'll also have to do some customization for your case.

Comment: Do you want to open a new page after submit the form? If so, you don't need to use AJAX.

Answer (score 0):

You could:

1. Build the html form with five text inputs, all stacked on top of one
   another (I think using position: absolute).
2. Place html table underneath inputs.
3. Place submit button underneath table.
4. Use javascript to:

   - hide the four text inputs that aren't currently being used
   - display the text input and corresponding color in the table when the user presses the +.
   - hide the current text input and show the next input when the user presses the +.
5. When user hits submit button, all five input values will be submitted to action='*.php'

Comment: Could you please tell me how to add the color? The sequence of the color is predefined, but how to add those colors?

Comment: are you using jQuery?